# aptana unistall from eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana

Finally I have decided to get rid of aptana from eclipse but the "Software update" menu shows "unistall" as disabled. How to enable unistall and release me of aptana woes? Is there a workaround or I simply go searching for aptana everywhere and delete all files which I will eventually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem at one point and never got a completely clean uninstall of Aptana from Eclipse.  I ended up just re-downloading a fresh copy of Eclipse and starting over.  I had to reinstall a few other plugins, but it was easier that trying to find all the Aptana leftovers.  At that point, the stand-alone (non-plugin) version of Aptana seemed to work better in general, so I just went with that.

Comment: sounds okay to me , let me wait for 30 more mins before i take your path

Answer (score 36):

[this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/166607/how-to-remove-aptana-from-eclipse) explains how to do it cleanly.  About Eclipse -> Installation Details and delete it from the Installed Software list.

Comment: I don't know why such an important feature is so well hidden in eclipse

Answer (score 10):

This was done on an Eclipse for PHP Developers v3.0.2
Go to:

> Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Uninstall or update
>   software that is already installed

Select "Installed Software" and pick the one you want to remove and select "Uninstall..."

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Just had the same problem. Couldn't find any good solutions around the internet, so I did the following:

`find / -name '*aptana*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`

Seems to have worked pretty well, though Aptana left little bits of evidence here and there.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run eclipse as Administrator and see what this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/166607/how-to-remove-aptana-from-eclipse/166615#166615) can do.

Comment: This, in conjunction with the "find / -name '*aptana*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf" answer seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Help-->About Eclipse SDK--> Installation Details --> Select Aptana --> Uninstall

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to revert to a previous configuration:

Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details

Than click on "Installation History" tab and select an earlier configuration that doesn't include Aptana (it will remove any component installed after it).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't mind completely reseting the eclipse environment. So, I used my OS' package manager (synaptic, ubuntu software Center, etc.) to remove eclipse then deleted /home/user/.eclipse from my home folder.